# Drag and Drop from View to View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, tableview, appcelerator

I am developing android application, and I have 2 TableView on my window. Each Table View Row has a Label on it with width = '100%'. I need to realize drag and drop this lables from one Table View to another. Please lead me the way. I am developing my project on Appcelerator Titanium.

Comment: I know how to drag and drop controls on the same view, i tested it and it works very good.. but what should i do when i want to drag control from view to view?

Comment: I suppose this issue not resolved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is very easy, answer is here

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/144674/drag-and-drop-from-view-to-view